# What is the difference between elm.json vs elm-package.json

Tags: elm

I have seen projects with one or both of them and both files contain dependencies and project info. What is the difference and are both valid with version 0.19.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`elm-package.json` is the package manifest used in 0.18. `elm.json` is the package manifest used in 0.19. It mostly serves the same purpose but uses a different schema that amongst other changes now separates direct from indirect dependencies.

Some more information is available in/via [the 0.19 upgrade guide](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#elmjson)

Comment: Then what's the difference between these and `package.json`?

Comment: Where have you seen `package.json` used with Elm?

Comment: In my own project. For example, I use elm-review, and the instructions say to use npm to install it. I guess they serve different purposes, elm.json for elm packages, package.json for js packages.

Comment: Yep. `npm` isn't normally used with Elm. But since elm packages don't support binaries, I suppose the most convenient package manager to use for that is `npm`.